# Is there a way to keep the grid output of a pandas dataframe when returning multiple values from a function?

Tags: python, pandas, statsmodels

All,

Is there a way to keep the grid display of a pandas dataframe or a statsmodels regression summary when returning multiple values from a function?

```
def lr(x,y,df):
    x=sm.add_constant(x)
    est=sm.OLS(y,x)
    est=est.fit()
    return (df.corr(),
            print('\n'),
            print('\n'),
            est.summary())
```

Take the above function for example. If I were just returning df.corr() it would keep the grid that normally comes when viewing a pandas dataframe. Same result if I only return est.summary(). However, when I want to return both they become much less aesthetically pleasing. I have tried putting them both in print() as well and same result. Please help!

EDITS:

```
def lr(x,y,df):
x=sm.add_constant(x)
est=sm.OLS(y,x)
est=est.fit()
return (HTML(df.corr()._repr_html_()),
        HTML(est.summary()._repr_html_()))
```

returns (IPython.core.display.HTML object, IPython.core.display.HTML object)

and

```
def lr(x,y,df):
x=sm.add_constant(x)
est=sm.OLS(y,x)
est=est.fit()
return (HTML(df.corr()._repr_html_() + est.summary()._repr_html_()))
```

gives the error listed in my comment below

Thanks!

Comment: Working in jupyter notebook by the way..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`df.corr()` and `est.summary()` both return `DataFrame` objects.

When a function returns just one, Jupyter displays that object by running the under the hood method `_repr_html_` which returns the text for the pretty `html` table and then displays it.  You could do the same thing by:

```
from IPython.core.display import HTML

HTML(df.corr()._repr_html_())
```

However, when you return them both wrapped in a tuple, Jupyter runs the `_repr_` method on the tuple which only returns text that isn't formatted as prettily.  If you made an assignment from the function:

```
my_results = lr(x, y, df)

my_results[0]
```

You'd get pretty formatting again.  Or:

```
my_results[1]
```

Also pretty formatting.  To get both, do this:

```
from IPython.core.display import HTML

HTML(df.corr()._repr_html_() + est.summary()._repr_html_())
```

Comment: I think we're definitely on the right track. Still having a couple of issues though. my_results[0] returns the correct output. However if I try the bottom cell you proposed as the return from the lr function I get an error saying 'DataFrame' object has no attribute '_repr_html'

Comment: @sokeefe1014 Don't be shy.  What issues?

Comment: sorry, accidentally hit enter when I was still typing the last comment. Edited above to show my attempts.

Comment: @sokeefe1014 you have a typo in the comment `_repr_html_`.  You were missing the final underscore.  I just fixed my post as well

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you!